# How to catch https data before send?

Tags: https

How can i catch https data(for example email) from browser before they are encrypted with ssl and send to the network? does anyone have idea?

I am looking for programmatical solution. How it works. I am not looking for any program,want to make my own.

Thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing email sniffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014129/writing-email-sniffer)

Comment: *https data(for example email)* sounds weird. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The author of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) has written [an article](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) about how they implemented the HTTPS capturing and decryption in Fiddler itself that will most likely be useful to you. Here's an excerpt:

> Q: The HTTPS protocol was designed to
> prevent traffic viewing and tampering.
> Given that, how can Fiddler2 debug
> HTTPS traffic?
>
> A: Fiddler2 relies on a
> "man-in-the-middle" approach to HTTPS
> interception.  To your web browser,
> Fiddler2 claims to be the secure web
> server, and to the web server,
> Fiddler2 mimics the web browser.  In
> order to pretend to be the web server,
> Fiddler2 dynamically generates a HTTPS
> certificate [...]

Comment: aa, thats what i am looking for,thx, can you fix the link on that article?

Comment: if you have any other idea instead of proxy, please let me know :P

Comment: @Dun Sorry about the link; it's fixed now. I think it will be easier with *some* kind of proxy, perhaps not just a full-fledged interactive proxy with a GUI. Writing a sniffer will be too much hassle IMHO. If you write a proxy, the browser will do all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for debugging, use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843/) or Fiddler.

### Firebug

You can watch requests and responses in the "Network" panel, HTTPS traffic too.

### Fiddler

Fiddler allows you to watch traffic from any application, but you need to install a fake certificate in order to watch HTTPS traffic.

Comment: i eddited my question, i dont want tp use any program. I am interested in how it really works to make my own program